# ActionBarSherlock targetSdkVersion

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm new to develop an android application based on API 10 (android 2.3.3), I want to add action bar in my application but API 10 don't support it. So I'm using ActionBarSherlock 4.0.0 to add action bar.

ActionBarSherlock v4.0.0 support at least api level 14 (sdk 4.0), so I set the projet build target for API 14 and targetsdkversion = 15

Now I want to create my new android project (using API 10 for runing on Android 2.3.3)
which "target SDK" and "compile with" should I choose? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter what targetSdk you use(I recommend API 17 though), you just have to build it with at least API 14.